# use variable as key name in mongo db with modifier

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to insert a bunch of arrays into mongoDB.

The data looks something like:

```
var places = {
    city: ['london', 'york', 'liverpool'],
    country: ['uk', 'france']
};
```

Each time I add an array, some of the entries could already be there, so I want to ensure there are no duplicates.

```
db.collection('places').ensureIndex({'city': 1}, {unique: true }, function(){ });
db.collection('places').ensureIndex({'country': 1}, {unique: true }, function(){ });
```

I then need to loop through the places object and add each item:

```
for(var key in places){

    db.collection('places').update({_id: 1}, { $addToSet: { key: { $each places[key] } } }, function(err, docs){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }else{
            console.log('success');
        }
    });

}
```

Here I need key to be the actual keys: 'city', 'country'. Rather than literally being 'key'. But I cant see how this can be achieved with with the modifiers in place.

Comment: It is probably a stupid question, but why don't you add an empty array to every document so you don't have this problem? :)

Comment: Could you expand on this please?

Comment: Hmm, I am beginning to think I misunderstood your question. Do you want to make sure that the content of your city/country array is unique or do you want to make sure there is only one array of city/country in your document?

Comment: I want to ensure the content of the city/country array is unique. Sorry I should actually be specifying and id in the update to ensure im updating the same arrays.

Comment: You are indeed correct that you will need to specify your _id as your first selector. The rest of your code seems about right. Let me know if you are stil having problems.

Comment: you can just add the key as a variable like that [key] and define it above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to build up your `$addToSet` value programmatically:

```
for(var key in places){
    var addToSet = {};
    addToSet[key] = { $each: places[key] };
    db.collection('places').update({_id: 1}, {$addToSet: addToSet}, function(err, docs){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }else{
            console.log('success');
        }
    });
}
```

But you can do this more efficiently by combining both updates into one:

```
var addToSet = {};
for(var key in places){
    addToSet[key] = { $each: places[key] };
}
db.collection('places').update({_id: 1}, {$addToSet: addToSet}, function(err, docs){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }else{
        console.log('success');
    }
});
```

Comment: Awesome that it can be done in a single query. Thanks!